# `python3.6 -m venv env` fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, python-venv

I am trying to create a virtual environment as:

```
python3.6 -m venv env
Error: Command '['/Users/jonathan/temp/django-example-channels/env/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My googling on the problem brings up many similar cases but all say they are on Ubuntu and Ubuntu related. Me I am on a Mac so I am thinking this is something else?

Don't really know what would be helpful but here is version information at least:

```
$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)
```

Comment: The recomended way to create a venv with a specific python version is `virtualenv env -p python3.6`, does that fail as well?

Comment: "-bash: virtualenv: command not found", interesting... :)

Comment: Using virtualenv requires that the virtualenv package first be installed.

Comment: The module `venv` is part of Python 3.6's standard library but conda recommends to use their own virtual environment system https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: The packaging of anaconda might have removed the venv package and if you want to install it, use `conda install virtualenv`

Comment: That being said, "miniconda3" on linux provides `venv`. Consider also that you have used a "custom" conda channel "django-example-channels" that might provide documentation.

Comment: I ran `conda install virtualenv` multiple times until it finally said that all requested packages already installed. But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: but `virtualenv env -p python3.6` worked...

Comment: Why are you trying to run `virtualenv` when conda has a built-in environment manager? `conda create -n testenv python=3.6`?

Comment: @darthbith The simple answer is "because the tutorial I was trying to follow used that and I didn't wanna digress from it because then I would be on my own..."

Answer (score 2):

So, it seems Anaconda was the problem. First virtualenv needed to be installed:

`conda install virtualenv`

I actually had to ru nthat multiple times before I got: `# All requested packages already installed.`. Don't know what's up with that, maybe my conda was to unupdated...

Then it still didn't work to create an environment as:

```
$ python3.6 -m venv env
Error: Command '['/Users/jonathan/temp/django-example-channels/env/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

However `$ python3.6 -m venv env` actually seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://gist.github.com/pandafulmanda/730a9355e088a9970b18275cb9eadef3) might be helpful in setting up and using a virtual environment in python3 with a Mac. In general though, I don't think you need to include the `.6` in command. Just using `$ python3 -m venv path/to/virtual/env` should work, as shown in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: There is no need to include it, but if he has multiple python versions that is how you'd want to discern between them.

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/305 indicates that Anaconda is not compatible with the virtualenv one get from pip install